# Проблема с d2d1: нарушение прав доступа при чтении

Tags: c++, visual-c++, изображения, directx, bitmap

Начал изучать d2d1 [по урокам этого парня](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RKZvT4U71rg) -
в итоге уже 2 дня не могу понять, что я делаю не так.

```
ID2D1Bitmap *bmp = NULL;
HRESULT hr;

IWICImagingFactory *wicFactory = NULL;
hr = CoCreateInstance(
    CLSID_WICImagingFactory,
    NULL,
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    IID_IWICImagingFactory,
    (LPVOID*)&wicFactory);

IWICBitmapDecoder *wicDecoder = NULL;
hr = wicFactory->CreateDecoderFromFilename(
    L"1.png",
    NULL,
    GENERIC_READ,
    WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad,
    &wicDecoder); // Вот здесь прерывается выполнение

IWICBitmapFrameDecode *wicFrame = NULL;
hr = wicDecoder->GetFrame(0, &wicFrame);

IWICFormatConverter *wicConverter = NULL;
hr = wicFactory->CreateFormatConverter(&wicConverter);

hr = wicConverter->Initialize(
    wicFrame,
    GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA,
    WICBitmapDitherTypeNone,
    NULL,
    0.0,
    WICBitmapPaletteTypeCustom
    );

hr = graphics->getTarget()->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(
    wicConverter,
    NULL,
    &bmp
    );

if (wicFactory) wicFactory->Release();
if (wicDecoder) wicDecoder->Release();
if (wicConverter) wicConverter->Release();
if (wicFrame) wicFrame->Release();
```

или так - http://codeshare.io/d3led

Уже и не знаю что мне делать, если честно. Ошибка -

```
 Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x000000013F2E5661 в Проект1.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x0000000000000000.
```

Вот все локальные переменные, очень хочу разобраться в вопросе, поэтому вбрасываю всё:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Картинки распихал по всем папкам с дебагом, в проект добавил, а код останавливается всё там же.

Comment: Думал закину ссылку потом, в итоге забыл. Учу д2д1 по урокам этого парня - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RKZvT4U71rg

Comment: Вы всегда можете править свои вопросы, для этого достаточно воспользоваться ссылкой "править" под метками вопроса.

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev, можно советовать нажать на ссылку [edit]. вставляется в комментарий она так: `[edit]`.

Comment: Почему HRESULT не проверяете?